# How to sum up currency values inside an array of objects in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have a return array of objects from a API call . And the object structure looks something like this ..

[image]

Like this the array can contain `n` number of Objects.

What I have to do is .. `sum up all the values of all the object's selectedMapping.cost` and display the sum.

But one problem is that the `costs` can be a bit tricky.

**They can be in format like .30 or 978. etc etc for which we have to assume 0.30 and 978.00 respectively. They can be null or undefined also in which case we have to default it to 0.0**

How can I achieve the sum in Angular JS ? How to handle the appropriate conversions and display the sum ?

Comment: toFixed(2) https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number/toFixed

Comment: Sorry to be rude but a user with your rep should know importance of sharing code and sample data(**not screenshot**).

Comment: Also to clarify, `Number.toFixed()` will return a **string** with format. You can compute total and then use `.toFixed` for display purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## This seems like a good time to use reduce

```js
const data = [
  {
    selectedMapping: {
      cost: ".30"
    }
  },
  {
    selectedMapping: {
      cost: "200"
    }
  },
  {
    selectedMapping: {
      cost: ".60"
    }
  },
  {
    selectedMapping: {
      cost: ".22"
    }
  },
  {
    selectedMapping: {
      cost: null
    }
  }];
  

const sumCost = (data) =>
  data.reduce(
    (cost, entry) => 
      cost + (parseFloat(entry.selectedMapping.cost) || 0), 
    0
  )
  

console.log(sumCost(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope I got you right, then this plunker I have created should do what you want:
https://embed.plnkr.co/zzQkybjND5xi2Uo7dNHZ/

Simply iterate over the array, check the value for null or undefined if so set it to 0.0 and sum all values.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution which handles undefined/null items

```
const sum = items.reduce((prevVal,item)=>{
  const selectedMapping = item.selectedMapping || null
  const cost = (isNaN(selectedMapping) && 'cost' in selectedMapping)? Number(selectedMapping.cost) : 0 
  return prevVal + cost
},0)
console.log(sum.toFixed(2))
```

[Here's a JSBin for it](http://jsbin.com/dafopi/edit?js,console)

[And reference for JavaScript’s Map, Reduce, and Filter](https://danmartensen.svbtle.com/javascripts-map-reduce-and-filter)

Answer (score 0):

you could map over the array and get the cost and then use R.sum method of ramdajs

```
const array = [
  {
    selectedMapping: {
      cost: ".30"
    }
  },
  {
    selectedMapping: {
      cost: "200"
    }
  },
  {
    selectedMapping: {
      cost: ".60"
    }
  },
  {
    selectedMapping: {
      cost: ".10"
    }
  },];

const currency = array.map(curr=>parseFloat(curr.selectedMapping.cost))
R.sum(currency);
```

[here](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.23.0#?const%20array%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20selectedMapping%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20cost%3A%20%22.30%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20selectedMapping%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20cost%3A%20%22200%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20selectedMapping%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20cost%3A%20%22.60%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20selectedMapping%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20cost%3A%20%22.10%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%5D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20currency%20%3D%20array.map%28curr%3D%3EparseFloat%28curr.selectedMapping.cost%29%29%0AR.sum%28currency%29%3B%20) is the code repel to do that.